# Surface area generated by revolving the astroid about the y-axis(Without parametrization)

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, surface-integrals, arc-length

Find the area of the surface generated by revolving the
astroid about the y-axis

an astroid is defined implicitly by:
$$x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}=a^{2/3}$$
now:
$$y = (a^{2/3}-x^{2/3})^{3/2}$$
$$y' = -\frac{\sqrt{a^{2/3}-x^{2/3}}}{x^{1/3}}$$

by arc length and surface area of revolution definition:

$$SA =2\pi \int_0^a x\sqrt{1+\frac{a^{2/3}-x^{2/3}}{x^{2/3}}} $$

did I get the surface area generated by the astroid right and how would you approach that integral

Comment: @Intelligentipauca surface area of an astroid

Comment: @Intelligentipauca what happen to $\pi$?

Comment: $SA = \int_a^b 2\pi x ds$

Comment: Is this a surface of revolution?

Comment: @user yes surface of revolution

Comment: Sorry I read wrong the question: Find the area of the surface generated by revolving the
astroid  
about the y-axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost done, indeed note that

$$\sqrt{1+\frac{a^{2/3}-x^{2/3}}{x^{2/3}}}=\sqrt{\frac{a^{2/3}}{x^{2/3}}}$$

therefore

$$2\pi \int_0^a x\sqrt{1+\frac{a^{2/3}-x^{2/3}}{x^{2/3}}}dx =2\pi \int_0^a x^{\frac23}a^{1/3}dx=2\pi\left[\frac35x^\frac 53a^\frac13\right]_0^a=\frac 65\pi a^2$$

Comment: that would be the upper part by symmetry the whole surface$$\frac{12}{5}\pi a^2$$????

Comment: @SirMrpirateroberts Yes this is an half, we need to take the double for the whole surface.

Comment: Thank you @user long time without seeing you, how are you doing

Comment: @SirMrpirateroberts You are welcome! I was studying  about astroids! ;)